# C# DllImport a function returning pointer to struct

Tags: c#, c++, interop

I'm trying to use a C++ DLL in C#.
I'm stuck at one function.
this is the function declaration in C++ header:

```
struct usb_relay_device_info EXPORT_API * usb_relay_device_enumerate(void);
```

and this is the struct in C++:

```
enum usb_relay_device_type
    {
        USB_RELAY_DEVICE_ONE_CHANNEL = 1,
        USB_RELAY_DEVICE_TWO_CHANNEL = 2,
        USB_RELAY_DEVICE_FOUR_CHANNEL = 4,
        USB_RELAY_DEVICE_EIGHT_CHANNEL = 8  
    };

struct usb_relay_device_info
{
    unsigned char *serial_number;
    char *device_path;
    usb_relay_device_type type;
    usb_relay_device_info* next;
};
```

this is how I'm importing in C#:

```
[DllImport("usb_relay_device.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern IntPtr usb_relay_device_enumerate();

public enum usb_relay_device_type
    {
    USB_RELAY_DEVICE_ONE_CHANNEL = 1,

    USB_RELAY_DEVICE_TWO_CHANNEL = 2,

    USB_RELAY_DEVICE_FOUR_CHANNEL = 4,

    USB_RELAY_DEVICE_EIGHT_CHANNEL = 8,
}

[StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct usb_relay_device_info
{
    /// unsigned char*
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string serial_number;

    /// char*
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string device_path;

    /// usb_relay_device_type
    public usb_relay_device_type type;

    /// usb_relay_device_info*
    public System.IntPtr next;
}
```

using like this:

```
IntPtr intPtr = usb_relay_device_enumerate();
```

but this always returns 0.
need help to understand what wrong I'm doing and how to correct it.
many thanks.

Comment: I ran your code verbatim and it functions exactly as I expected. The only thing I added was an implementation of usb_relay_device_enumerate(): extern "C"  struct usb_relay_device_info * usb_relay_device_enumerate(void)
{
 struct usb_relay_device_info * retn = new usb_relay_device_info();
 retn->next = new usb_relay_device_info();
 retn->next->next = new usb_relay_device_info();
 return retn;
} and an entry in the .def file to export it. Perhaps you can test usb_relay_device_enumerate() in the C++ code and make sure it returns something non-null?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code.  Getting IntPtr.Zero would almost always mean that it did not find any USB devices.  Make sure you plugged them in and have a good driver for them.  The manufacturer always supplies a basic test program, be sure to run it so you know the hardware is okay.